# UIImageView is floating around on screen after switching view

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, ios6

I'm trying to make a compass.

Basically I use an image of a compass needle as the directions-thing for the compass. It's animating fine around the center of the compass UNTIL I switch view, or add another view (ex. UIActionView or switch to another view controller):

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{

            float oldRadian = (-manager.heading.trueHeading *M_PI /180.0f);
            float newRadian = (-newHeading.trueHeading *M_PI /180.0f);

            CABasicAnimation *animation;
            animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
            animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRadian];
            animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRadian];
            animation.duration = 0.5f;

            [compassArrow.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
            compassArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRadian);
}
```

After this I'm switching to another view controller that is the compassArrow imageview that was animating & started floating around.

**Any ideas why this happens??**

Comment: how did you setframe of compassArrow? paste that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the removeFromSuperlayer-method before I change view. Problem was that I created multiple animations for the same key (@"animateMyRotation").

```
[compassArrow.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set Compass arrow center as your Compass center

```
compassArrow.center = CompassImage.center;
```

Hope this Helps you

Comment: CompassImage is the imageview of Round Compass image

Comment: still the same. the image doesn't move to another point any more, but it's still floating around like it were floating on water or something.

Comment: everytime i update the heading, it moves from a random point around the screen to the center of the compass now. it's like it wants to be on two places at the same time.

Comment: You are Checking in Device or Simulator

Comment: any ideas? i'm getting crazy over this.. :/

Comment: What are the frames of both Compassimage and CompassArrow that you are adding

Comment: so i don't really know if i'm adding them as a frame.

Comment: something is happening when i'm switching the view controller.

Comment: Go to your .xib and Click on imageview and then click on sizeInspector on the left side panel of your xcode you will find the frame

Answer (score 1):

For the `compassArrow` imageView set the anchor point. so that it will rotate according to the anchor point.

use     `compassArrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);`

hope i will help you.....

Comment: almost. it's not floating around anymore, but it's still moving to another position, like in the picture. but this time it's still moving around its' own center.

Answer (score 0):

Get your image view frame first. For that you can type `NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", compassArrow.frame.origin.x,compassArrow.frame.origin.y,compassArrow.frame.size.width,compassArrow.frame.size.height);` in viewDidLoad.
Note down the frame. Then in viewWillAppear method, add the line.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:YES];
   [compassArrow setFrame:CGRectMake(CMPASSARROWFRAME.x, CMPASSARROWFRAME.y, CMPASSARROWFRAME.width, CMPASSARROWFRAME.height)];
}
```

Note this 'CMPASSARROWFRAME' is the frame of your `compassArrow` frame.

Comment: i get an error... "MainViewController.m:1002:14: Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')"

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", compassArrow.frame);

Comment: too get the frame for the compassArrow.

Comment: returns "160.000000 494.000000 0.000000 0.000000"

Comment: and i tried putting "    [directionsArrow setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 494, 120, 120)];" in the viewWillAppear method, but still the same problem.

Comment: I put the NSLog(compassArrow.frame) inside the didUpdateHeading method. It changes like this when it's "working": "84.104683 418.104675 151.790634 151.790634"...

Comment: what i also noticed is that it continues updating the frame-position after i open another view controller, like it's running in the background. maybe that's the problem... you think of any way i can stop the animation/stop the updating? tried [locationManager stopUpdatingHeading], but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

please check the frame before and after the switch and see whether they are same.If they are not same then it means that you are setting its frame wrongly somewhere .If the frame is the same before and after switching view then the problem is with layer transformation.Somewhere or the other you might have changed the anchor point or the layer location.

find out where it gets updated,use break points,follow the control flow and track the place where frame gets updates.You can find the step into button above the debug console in xcode.

Comment: i put a NSLog to check the frame position before and after the change, and what i noticed was that it continues updating the frame-position after i open another view controller, like it's running in the background. maybe that's the problem.. what do you think?